# Resolve partial URLs in .NET

Tags: c#, f#, uri

Suppose I have some links from a web page (`https://example.com/xyz`) like this:

- `/abc`
- `another.com`
- `#def`

I would like to "fix up" these links given the URL of the web page:

- `/abc`   ->   `https://example.com/abc`
- `another.com`   ->   `https://another.com`
- `#def`   ->   `https://example.com/xyz#def`

How should I do this in .NET Core (C# / F#)?

Answer (score 1):

The `Uri.TryCreate` method handles two of your three cases in the way you want:

```
let ok, url = Uri.TryCreate(Uri("https://example.com/xyz"), "/abc")
// https://example.com/abc

let ok, url = Uri.TryCreate(Uri("https://example.com/xyz"), "another.com")
// https://example.com/another.com

let ok, url = Uri.TryCreate(Uri("https://example.com/xyz"), "#def")
// https://example.com/xyz#def
```

In the second case, `another.com` is just interpreted as a file name rather than a domain name. This is quite sensible because the case is ambiguous.

I don't think there is a way to automatically handle the second case in the way you want using a built-in .NET method. You will probably need to implement the logic for that yourself. It depends on what exactly you want - if you want to turn `<domain>.<tld>` into `https://<domain>.<tld>`, you could possibly check if the string matches the `<domain>.<tld>` pattern (and ensure that `<tld>` is valid to avoid turning `index.html` into `https://index.html`) and then do the transformation yourself.